# Mixing overriding and overloading in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, computer-science

I don't understand why I have this error `error: no matching function for call to ‘Child::m(Mother&)` when I try to compile my code.

From what I understand: 
since the type of c is `Child` and Child::m have a parameter of type `Child` while m is of type `Mother` in `c.m(m)` then it's the function m() from the Mother class who need to be called.

```
class Mother{
 public: 
  void m(const Mother&) {
  }
};

class Child: public Mother{
 public:
  void m(const Child&) {
  }
};



int main() {
  Mother m;
  Child c;
  c.m(m);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `Child` class has no member function `m` that takes a `Mother`. It is hidden by the `m` declared in `Child`. You can unhide it by adding `using Mother::m;` in `Child`.